How can I prepare tableware properly while maintaining efficiency and cleanliness?
I have to plate 80 small appetizer cups that we used to stack with trays. Now management said to stop stacking trays on top of the cups. (There are other appetizers. I just lowered the number.)
(Per tray: 12 appetizer cups fit.)
I think it's very unreasonable because the stacking saves so much time and space. Is there some way to keep cleanliness and efficiency?

Has your management explained why you should stop the practice? Hygiene, damage, risk of toppling over? Depending on the reason, we can suggest different solutions.

If the issue is concern that the top of the cups come into contact with the bottom of the trays which might have been set on an unclean surface, they might accept your placing the trays upside down on the cups.  If not, you might have to consider something like a baker's rack

Your best option is to wrap completed trays of appetisers in cling film (also called saran wrap, plastic wrap, etc.). This would address the issues with hygiene of the potentially unclean bottom of the tray touching the top of the clean cups. It would also help with balance as the film would add a bit of friction preventing the stacked trays from sliding and toppling over. Additionally it would be more hygienic as well as it will prevent any airborne contaminants from getting into the cups as well.
The easiest and quickest way to do this is to roll out some film roughly twice the length of the tray and cutting it, then placing the tray on one side of it, filling it, and wrapping the other side over the top.

Thank you. Sounds brilliant

Only if the relevant heath inspector approves. Which is almost certainly where management got the idea that the old way was bad. Keep the inspector happy with whatever solutions you consider, and management should be happy as well.
